# Node.js and Socket.io UTF8 Validation TypeError coming from ws

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Getting this error when validating data received from the client through socket.io.

```
C:\Users\Rayce\Documents\SENG513\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:532
6:23:55 PM web.1 |              if (!Validation.isValidUTF8(messageBuffer)) {
6:23:55 PM web.1 |                             ^
6:23:55 PM web.1 |  TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValidUTF8' of undefined
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at C:\Users\Rayce\Documents\SENG513\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:532:28
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at C:\Users\Rayce\Documents\SENG513\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:368:7
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at C:\Users\Rayce\Documents\SENG513\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\ws\lib\PerMessageDeflate.js:249:5
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:355:3)
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:346:7)
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:89:5)
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:79:3)
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at TransformState.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:54:12)
6:23:55 PM web.1 |      at Zlib.callback (zlib.js:613:5)
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
6:23:55 PM web.1 Exited with exit code 1
```

Editing out this section of code in Receiver.js,

```
if (!Validation.isValidUTF8(messageBuffer)) {
  self.error('invalid utf8 sequence', 1007);
  return;
}
```

stops the error from occuring but I would prefer a better solution as I'd like to use NPM and can't be bothered to redo this every time an update occurs.

I have also tried installing utf-8-validate into the node_modules folder of socket.io with no success

Comment: Could you solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem, plus it for anyone can help ^-^

Answer (score 3):

Just Install or run this command and good to go:

```bash
npm install ws bufferutil utf-8-validate
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in a NextJS app (13.0.1) using socket.io.

I solved installing `webpack-node-externals`:

```
npm install webpack-node-externals --save-dev
```

And then adding to `next.config.js`:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
    webpack(config) {
        config.externals = [nodeExternals()];    
        return config;
    },
    ...
});
```

It may not solve the OP case specifically, but may be useful for anyone having this issue with NextJS.

For those not using NextJS, adding the code below to `webpack.config.js` should also work:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: upgrade `ws` v2.x can fix this!

change **Receiver.js** in `ws`module like this:

```
var isValidUTF8 = require('./Validation')
...
if (!isValidUTF8(messageBuffer)) {
  ...
}
```

you can do this just make it work, but it's not a good solution for this, it seems like that there is a wrong export of **Validation** module, you may send a PR to `ws` to fix this.